# Regex para adicionar um nível de hierarquia em todas as regras CSS

Tags: css, regex, replace

I wanna do a regex to use in the sublime's "Find & Replace" to do add a hierarchy level (a class named "myClass", for example) to all css rules.

Current code

```
div {
   width: 100%;
   border: 5px solid #F00;
}

.red-button {
   background: #F00;
}

div .red-button {
   color: #000;
}
```

What I need

```
.myClass div {
   width: 100%;
   border: 5px solid #F00;
}

.myClass .red-button {
   background: #F00;
}

.myClass div .red-button {
   color: #000;
}
```

the css file is too large, I think that a regular expression can help

Comment: Could you translate the title as well, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

```
^([^\n{]+\{)
```

**Replace with:** `.myClass $1`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/aG2tJ2/1

**Sample text**

```
div {
   width: 100%;
   border: 5px solid #F00;
}

.red-button {
   background: #F00;
}

div .red-button {
   color: #000;
}
```

**After Replacement**

```
.myClass div {
   width: 100%;
   border: 5px solid #F00;
}

.myClass .red-button {
   background: #F00;
}

.myClass div .red-button {
   color: #000;
}
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\n{]+                  any character except: '\n' (newline),
                             '{' (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly!